# Update columns with Editor template in Kendo UI MVC

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I'm a newbie in MVC and Kendo UI, use the Kendo UI MVC to create the Grid using Ajax binding, and add combobox in one column using editor template. When i select in combobox, it will display DataValueField in the column (DistDetSubName), But the column DistDetID don't display something.. How can i get DataTextField combobox in this column (DistDetID) ???

Grid with editor template in column like below code :

```
  columns.Bound(e => e.BatNbr).Hidden(true);
 columns.Bound(e => e.RecordID).Hidden(true);
 columns.Bound(e => e.DistDetID).EditorTemplateName("test");
 columns.Bound(e => e.DistDetSubName);
```

Code in test.cshtml in Editor Templates folder:

```
@model string

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                      .Name("DistDetSubName")
                              .DataTextField("DistDetID")
                              .DataValueField("DistDetSubName")

      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetDist", "DM");

          })
          .ServerFiltering(false);
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in test.cshtml in Editor Templates folder:

```
@model string

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                  .Name("DistDetID")
                          .DataTextField("DistDetSubName")
                          .DataValueField("DistDetID")

  .DataSource(source =>
  {
      source.Read(read =>
      {
          read.Action("GetDist", "DM");

      })
      .ServerFiltering(false);
  })
```

[Refrence Link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates)